# Convert dataframe column into date type with last business day of the month

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
       Date     number
0    AUG 17        1.0
1    AUG 17        1.6
2    FEB 18        1.0
3    MAR 18        1.7
4    APR 18        6.0
5    Jan 19        1.0
6    Apr 19        2.0
7    Jun 19        7.1
8    Jan 20        5.5
9    Feb 20        8.6
```

And I would like to convert the `Date` column into date type (with the last business day of the month (Monday- Friday)), so that I would get the following output:

```
            Date     number
0    2017-08-31        1.0
1    2017-08-31        1.6
2    2018-02-28        1.0
3    2018-03-30        1.7
4    2018-04-30        6.0
5    2019-01-31        1.0
6    2019-04-30        2.0
7    2019-06-28        7.1
8    2020-01-31        5.5
9    2020-02-28        8.6
```

NOTICE that some of my months are in CAPS.

I tried:

```
date = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%b%Y').date() for x in df['Date']]
```

But keeps me giving matching error, I assume it is because some months are in CAPS.

Comment: business day .. usually Mo-Fr/Mo-Sa?

Comment: @MrFuppes the year is in the first df, the number is the abbreviation of the year

Comment: @Patrick Artner Monday-Friday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for? make use of the [capitalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) method (which is also awailable in `pandas`) to parse the date and add an offset from `pd.offsets` to get the appropriate business day:

```
import pandas as pd
# example df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['AUG 17', 'aug 17', 'FEB 18', 'MAR 18'], 
                   'number': [1, 1.6, 1, 1.7]})
# convert to datetime after capitalizing the month name, add offset so you can get last business day of month
df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.capitalize(), format='%b %y') + 
              pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1))
# df
#         Date  number
# 0 2017-08-31     1.0
# 1 2017-08-31     1.6
# 2 2018-02-28     1.0
# 3 2018-03-30     1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the mistake I was making was that the Year part was also abbreviated. So it should be `%y` instead of `%Y` and also it should have a space between the month and the year : `%b %y`

So to achieve the output I wanted:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# convert the string dates into date type
df['Date'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%b %y').date() for x in df['Date']]

#convert to Business Days (Monday-Friday)
df = df.assign(Date=df['Date'] + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1))
```

Comment: Yes, I will post my code. I will just post my answer (however yours is good and thank you), because mine is a little different

Comment: using a list comprehension here I'd consider *bad practice* (inefficient at least) - if you use `pandas`, let the pandas code do the iterations instead of doing it in your Python script. you can easily modify my answer accordingly.